Question about a specific proof for the surjectivity of the complex exponential function
As part of a specific proof i have to show the following
Let $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ be a differentiable path with $\gamma(0)=1$ and $\gamma(1) = z$
With $g: [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}, T \mapsto \gamma\prime(T) \cdot \exp{(-\int_{0}^{T} \frac{\gamma\prime(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt)}$
Show that $g\prime(T) = 0$
As of right now i dont have any idea why this should be true. After calculating the integral i got the expression $g = \frac{\gamma\prime(T)}{\gamma(T)}$
For the derivative of this to be $0$ would mean that this a constant expression. But why should the derivative of a differentiable path be its multiplicative inverse (or a multiple of it)
So i would be very thankful for some ideas that help me to understand the problem.
I apologise for any errors in the question. English isnt my native language.

You should not calculate the integral (and can't). Your expression of $g$ is false. Further, the definition of $g$ is not good for the problem:
It should be $\gamma$ instead of $\gamma'$ in front of $\exp$, i.e.
$$g(T) = \gamma(T)\exp\left(-\int_{0}^T \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt\right)$$
Then by product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$g'(T) = \gamma'(T)\exp\left(-\int_{0}^T \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt\right)-\gamma(T)\exp\left(-\int_{0}^T \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt\right)\frac{d}{dT}\left(-\int_{0}^T \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt\right) = \left(\gamma'(T)-\gamma(T)\cdot\frac{\gamma'(T)}{\gamma(T)}\right)\exp\left(-\int_{0}^T \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt\right) = 0$$
for all $T \in [0,1]$. So, $g$ is constant.
Now, $g(0) = \gamma(0)\cdot\exp(0) = 1$ and $g(1)=\gamma(1)\cdot\exp\left(-\int_{0}^1 \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt\right)=z\exp(w)$ with $w:=-\int_{0}^1 \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt$. As $g$ is constant it follows $1=g(0)=g(1)=z\exp(w)$ and therefore $z=\frac{1}{\exp(w)} = \exp(-w)$. Thus $\exp$ is indeed surjective.

Thank you for the anwser! I checked my question sheet again and g ist writen exactly as i put it in the question. But i will ask if there may be an error in the task.
May i ask why i cant calculate the integral? Shouldnt it just be the logarithm of $\gamma(T)$

@SLNWRK Yes, $\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}$ is the logarithmic derivative of $\gamma$, but you want essentially to prove that $\log(z)$ exists, so you cant use $\log$. The integral for $T=1$ would be $\log(\gamma(1))-\log(\gamma(0)) = \log(z)-\log(1)$.
